# Easy way to shell into a GCP container template VM by name?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google Cloud "Instance Templates" and specifying a "Container Image".

[image]

This creates a container with my docker image, but it uses a auto-generated name (i.e. `klt-my-image-wczt`.

The steps to get into the container are very long:

1. SSH into container
2. `sudo su`
3. `docker ps` to see image name
4. `docker exec -ti $name /bin/bash`

Is there an easier way to get into the container, or at least not have to check and copy/paste the different container name each time the VM is recreated?

Comment: Use/modify `cloud-init` to name your container. https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/run-container-instance#using_cloud-init_with

Comment: @JohnHanley can you elaborate on that? I don't see any mention of changing the name there

Comment: In my link look for the line `ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name=mycloudservice ...` Notice the docker command. You can set the container name.

Comment: Does John hanley comment help you to resolve your issue?

Comment: it looks like that would require me to change how i deploy instead of using instance templates? `cloud-init` seems to be a different product if i read that correctly.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a different product. The cloud-init tool expects its configuration in the value of the user-data key of the instance metadata. You can configure metadata in instance templates. This [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates#create_a_new_instance_template) has more information,